# How to make an image's color look consistent across different applications?

Tags: color-profile, color-reproduction

One time I had some images for buttons for users to click on, and they looked bright and sharp on a Mac's Preview app, and on some other graphics apps on the PC, but when it was displayed on Chrome on a Mac, the color became dull.  Someone suggested it was due to "color profile" in the image, but is there a way to remove it, if PhotoShop is not available to me and I have to rely on bundled or freeware tools on the Mac or the PC?

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in working with color profiles with free software, GIMP does that. In their documentation, you can find [background info on color management](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-imaging-color-management.html), [enabling color management](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-display-filter-dialog.html), and [customizing color management](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-pimping.html#gimp-prefs-color-management).

I did some digging, though, and it turns out that [this is a known issue for Chrome](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15283/google-chrome-for-mac-css-colors-and-display-profiles). According to the [issue ticket](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=44872), it's been an issue for two years!

Answer (score 1):

If you're working on a Mac I suggest [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.com/). It optimizes your PNG and removes all colorprofiles and unnecessary stuff. Win/win situation.

On a windows machine try [PNGcrush](http://www.freemancontingent.ie/archives/623)